# Import-values feature in requirements.yaml of Kubernetes-helm is not working

Tags: charts, kubernetes-helm

I am facing a problem with [helm subcharts](https://docs.helm.sh/developing_charts/#importing-child-values-via-requirements-yaml), the `import-values` features in requirements.yaml is not working.

**What was done:**

created parent chart with following values.yaml

```
# parent's values.yaml file
myimports:
  myint: 0
  mybool: false
  mystring: "helm rocks!"
```

created subchart1 chart with following values.yaml

```
# subchart1's values.yaml file
default:
  data:
    myint: 999
    mybool: true
```

created requirements.yaml in parent chart.

```
# parent's requirements.yaml file
dependencies:
  - name: subchart1
    repository: http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts
    version: 0.1.0
    ...
    import-values:
      - child: default.data
        parent: myimports
```

executed following commands

```
 $ helm package subchart1
 $ helm dependency update parent/
 $ helm dependency build parent/
```

**What happens:**

1. both update and build command gets completed successfully.
2. subchart1 gets downloaded from local helm server and gets placed in ./parent/charts/ directory

**Expected output:**

```
# parent's final values
myimports:
  myint: 999
  mybool: true
  mystring: "helm rocks!"
```

**Problem:**

The parent chart's values.yaml is not getting updated.

helm version:

```
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.7.0", GitCommit:"08c1144f5eb3e3b636d9775617287cc26e53dba4", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.7.0", GitCommit:"08c1144f5eb3e3b636d9775617287cc26e53dba4", GitTreeState:"clean"}`
```

Answer (score -1):

If you mean the values.yaml of parent is not updated; it is not expected either. The final effective values are updated at runtime. It doesn't update your values.yaml file.

You might run `helm install --dry-run --debug parent` and see the effect under the `COMPUTED VALUES:` section of output.